# My OneDrive got created with Chinese default folders

Tags: windows-10, language, onedrive

Something got wrong when setting up my OneDrive account, and the default folders got created in Chinese (or another Asian language, I can not tell), as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

The language I wanted is English US, keyboard layout German, and the region Germany, and that is what I specified when installing Windows 10 / setting up OneDrive.

Can I tell OneDrive to recreate the default folders, or should I rename the folders myself?

Answer (score 1):

From the article
[Change views on the OneDrive website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-views-on-the-onedrive-website-7465991b-6882-4f0d-9a0a-2b2a455798cc) :

> If you are signed in with a Microsoft account, to view your OneDrive in a different language, select Settings at the top of the page, then select the language currently displayed to open the Language pane.

Other sources for the language problem might be your Office 365 account
(if you have one),
or whether you are located in a Chinese-speaking country.

If none of the above helps or is relevant, a question : are you using One Drive for Business?